NEXT.JS 14: Query external API with same JWT-Auth
I want to access an external API with NextJS.
My authentication runs via NextAuth and has an Azure AD provider. The login works.
The external API also has the same authentication via Azure AD. But now I need this token for each fetch.
This is my auth.ts:
import { NextAuthOptions, Session } from "next-auth";
import AzureADProvider from "next-auth/providers/azure-ad";

interface CustomUser {
  name?: string | null;
  email?: string | null;
  image?: string | null;
  idToken?: string;
}

export interface CustomSession extends Session {
  user?: CustomUser;
}

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  session: {
    strategy: "jwt",
  },
  pages: {
    signIn: "/login",
  },
  providers: [
    AzureADProvider({
      clientId: process.env.CLIENT_ID as string,
      clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET as string,
      tenantId: process.env.TENANT_ID,
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    jwt({ token, account }) {
      if (account) {
        token.idToken = account.id_token;
      }
      return token;
    },
    session({ session, token }) {
      const customSession = session as CustomSession;
      if (token.idToken && customSession.user) {
        customSession.user.idToken = token.idToken as string;
      }
      return customSession;
    },
  },
  secret: process.env.NEXTAUTH_SECRET,
};

I can then always access my token in the page via useSession as follows:
const { data: session }: { data: CustomSession | null | undefined } =
    useSession();

Is this a secure way to communicate via the external API or is there a better alternative?
Exactly the approach described above
